# Downloading file from artifactory, using API Key for authentication

Tags: python, artifactory

I have looked into the documentation : https://github.com/parallels/artifactory
And here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API

But couldn't find a good example of sending a request to download a file with it's url and use API-Key for authentication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 options for using the API key for [authentication](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-Authentication):

- Basic authentication using your username and API Key
- Using a dedicated header (X-JFrog-Art-Api) with your API Key

For example:

```
curl -uadmin:AKCp2WXCNDRsYwX8vd83KsxEnh1tMs6Qp1Dm8M7oDtA464Nz3kmjgrZRnbtJAXm2AfDEpMhfJ -ocommons-collections-3.1.jar http://localhost:8081/artifactory/jcenter/apache-collections/commons-collections/3.1/commons-collections-3.1.jar
```

or

```
curl -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api: AKCp2WXCNDRsYwX8vd83KsxEnh1tMs6Qp1Dm8M7oDtA464Nz3kmjgrZRnbtJAXm2AfDEpMhfJ" -ocommons-collections-3.1.jar http://localhost:8081/artifactory/jcenter/apache-collections/commons-collections/3.1/commons-collections-3.1.jar
```

Comment: Thanks, I used Python Requests, and this got it to work: 

download_request = requests.get(downloadUrl, headers={"X-JFrog-Art-Api": artifactoryApiKey})